# Dart maps, how to replace specific key value in a list<map> based on its key id?

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

```
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> products = [
    {'id': 24, 'time': '2019-11-24 00:00:00.000'},
    {'id': 36, 'time': '2019-11-23 00:00:00.000'},
    {'id': 48, 'time': '2019-11-24 00:00:00.000'},
  ];
```

In the code above I want to replace 'time' entry '2019-11-24 00:00:00.000' to '2019-10-26 00:00:00.000' for the 'id' 48.

Comment: If id is unique, you've got the wrong data structure.  It should be a single Map with the id as the key.  Replacing it would be a simple assignment.  Iterating over a list to find a particular one is almost always a code smell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
   products.whereFirst((x) => x["id"] == 48)["time"] = "2019-10-26 00:00:00.000";
```

Comment: @Akif, Your flutter answers are really informative.

Comment: Thank you, @Ketan Ramteke :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way how you can do it:

```dart
    void main() { 
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> products = [
        {'id': 24, 'time': '2019-11-24 00:00:00.000'},
        {'id': 36, 'time': '2019-11-23 00:00:00.000'},
        {'id': 48, 'time': '2019-11-24 00:00:00.000'},
      ];
      
       products = products.map((product){
        if(product["id"] == 48){
          return {...product, 'time': '2019-10-26 00:00:00.000'};
        }
         return product;
      }).toList();
      
      print(products.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks dear, "return {...product, 'time': '2019-10-26 00:00:00.000'};" worked for me :)

Comment: Glad it helped, happy coding.